# PDO connection not working although it's enabled in the php.ini

Tags: php, pdo

My connection parameters are correct since I use to make successfull connection with mysqli. But since switching to PDO, I got trouble and the exception `Unknown MySQL server host` is always thrown.

My relevant code is this:

```
class UpdateStock{
     public function __construct(){
        try{
           $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:8889;dbname=mydatabasename', 'root', 'root');   
           $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

           echo 'connection succedded'; 

        }catch(PDOException $e){
         echo $e;//Always got exception
        }
    }

}//End of class

$updateStock = new UpdateStock;
```

My php.ini file enable the PDO option for mysql:
`extension=pdo_mysql.so`

MAMP is running fine, so what seems to be wrong with the PDO not being able to connect.

Comment: Are you sure your MySQL listens on port 8889? The usual port is 3306. Furthermore, why do you define connection details in the constants, if you don't use them when creating the connection?

Comment: Hi, that used to work fine with `mysqli`, no it's not the 3306.

Comment: if you open a command prompt and type `ping localhost` what do you get back ?

Comment: I *think* the port is a separate option in the DSN: `mysql:host=xxx;port=xxx;dbname=xxx`

Comment: Try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. You can read the comments in [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) for further explanation.

Comment: @BlakeSchwendiman is correct see the documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php#refsect1-ref.pdo-mysql.connection-description `port` is indeed a separate option.

Comment: port can be in a separate option, but in my case mysql and mysqli were not using the same port, mysql in fact wasn't using a port at all. I got that as the default value when running `phpinfo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked phpinfo to see which port MySQL server is listening, and I found it empty value (no port specified):

[image]

So simply I removed the port from the host value to get it to work:

```
   $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabasename', 'root', 'root');
```

`mysqli` however used the port `3306`. I thought PDO and mysqli will be using same port but seems I was wrong about that :)